# Implement multi-tenancy in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, crm

Let's say I'm using Salesforce as the CRM for a resturant business. I have everything already implemented and working fine but now more customers (restaurant franchises) want to be partners. I want to keep all the structure as it is right now but be able to separate what each franchise can see (only their own specific data). How could I achieve this? I was wondering if having another Parent Account as the franchise would be a good solution.

For example:

Franchise(Grand-Parent Account) => Restaurant (Parent Account) => Services, Employees etc (Contacts)

Answer (score 0):

There are code-free solutions for this, consider asking at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

If you want them to be normal (internal) users - look into sharing rules. But maybe your internal users should see everything. There's "Experience Cloud" (formerly known as Community or Portal) solution, for both your customers and partners. You'd take a contact and promote them to portal user. SF security would make sure they can see only data related to their account + (if you want) you could expose contact us form, FAQs, ideas, some Chatter collaboration. They'd get their own logins, you could even have multiple communities (say 1 restaurant chain is big and demands special functionality or they'd like to log in with their Single Sign-On)...

There's a license cost but it's much cheaper than for internal users. Communities work well for "normal" users but if your business is dormant most of the time and you have activity spikes (fairs / expos / events) - you could have volume-based licenses like 10K logins/month.

So yeah, search around https://www.salesforce.com/products/experience-cloud/overview/ view some videos on YT or check trailhead courses. Experiment in your developer edition and post a question if you're stuck?